# Get mm dd yyyy from user input

Tags: c++, string

This is a really simple program I have to make but I'm going blank on how to do it.

Basically the user inputs the date in the from mm/dd/yyyy and all I have to do is separate the values and output them on separate lines.

This is what i have so far:

```
int main ()
{
    char cMonth[2];
    char cDay [2];
    char cYear[4];

    cout << "Enter a date in the form mm/dd/yyy: " ;

    cin.get(cMonth,3,'/');
    cin.ignore(2,'/');
    cin.get(cDay, 4, '/');
    cin.ignore(2,'/');
    cin.get(cYear, 5);

    cout << cMonth << endl << cDay << endl << cYear << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My program compiles but when it runs it gives wrong output, for example if i put `04/13/2013` the output will be:

```
0413
13
2013
```

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that your `char` buffers aren't big enough to hold the null terminator, so you're writing the null terminator past the end of the buffer. In the case of `cMonth` and `cDay`, this apparently causes them to run into each other because they are stored adjacently on the stack (don't rely on that behaviour!)

You need to make them at least one byte longer, i.e. 3, 3, and 5 bytes long. Be aware that your code is vulnerable to a buffer overflow; you may want to adjust your `.get` parameters so that they can't possibly overflow the buffers, or make the buffers longer.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do this sort of thing is to simply read the entire string at once, then use the POSIX standard function `strptime()` to convert it to a broken-down struct containing the parts. Like this:

```
string in;
cin >> in; // TODO: check return value
struct tm out = {};
strptime(in.c_str(), "%m/%d/%Y", &out); // TODO: check return value
cout << out.tm_mon+1 << endl << out.tm_mday << endl << out.tm_year+1900 << endl;
```

Note that the fields in `struct tm` have "strange" semantics -- that's why the integer offsets are applied like that. Oh well, chalk that one up to history.

Now not only can you print the parts, you can pass the struct to other functions like `strftime`, `mktime`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
int main ()
{
    char cMonth[3];
    char cDay [3];
    char cYear[5];

    cout << "Enter a date in the form mm/dd/yyyy: " ;

    cin.get(cMonth,3,'/');
    cin.ignore(2,'/');
    cin.get(cDay, 4, '/');
    cin.ignore(2,'/');
    cin.get(cYear, 5);

    cout << cMonth << endl << cDay << endl << cYear << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1, but a small niggle: the prompt should be `yyyy` instead of `yyy`